# Why cant I provoke TCP into splitting send() into multiple recv()

Tags: sockets, blocking, recv

My long term understanding of sockets was that a call to recv() could not be relied upon to return the requested amount of data (be it blocking socket or not)

I was trying to prove this to a colleague by sending large (1mb) amounts of data in one call to send (from my home, to his home over a works VPN network - multiple routers wifi etc involved)

The sockets are blocking so I don't expect the send() to return anything but 1mb and do it in one go, but I did expect the recv() calls to return less than 1mb even though the socket is blocking.

The background for this test was to persuade him that we need a length and payload in the message protocol so you know where messages start/end, and you can't rely on one recv() call returning one message.  Also to show him a simple recv() isn't even enough if we do have this protocol, we need to recv() in a loop, even for say the 4 byte message length field, incase recv() doesn't return the requested size.

Is my understanding of TCP comms wrong?  Have I just been doing it overkill all these years?  If not how can i force these recv() to come in fragmented?

Comment: I'm surprised you got all 1MB in a single receive. That's likely hundreds of packets buffered before returning from the `recv()` call. Try with 10MB, or even 100MB.

Comment: This is what I thought!, 1mb, without a split, unlikely.  I started to wonder if its the VPN software, so that its irrelevant how many types of network are between us, the VPN S/W is effectively allowing unlimited size TCP packets to be reconstructed on the other side?  Maybe I try with two laptops over wifi at home?

Comment: Right, so I did a noddy app sending 16k heartbeats every second, and did it purely over wifi at home.  Went outside house to the point the HB stopped and not once did i receive a partial recv(), it paused, but when I came back in range continued

Comment: So something I've not mentioned, we are using SSL for the connection, but we did a lot of our tests on both SSL and non-SSL.  My noddy 16k test above was done on SSL (C# SslStream wrapping TCPClient.GetStream).  If my reader waits 5 sec at link up before issuing a read, and I ensure my sender sends 2 distinct messages in that time, the receiver gets 2 reads!!!!!  But if i swap to non-ssl (either using Client.GetStream or Client.Client) then the reader gets both messages in 1 read.  Im going to repeat the walking outside house test on non-ssl

Comment: Walking to the brink of the wifi connection i cannot force the recv to get a partial read on a non-ssl socket.  Am i baning my head against a wall trying to "force" this split condition?

Comment: OK, so wacking the message size upto 1mb on wifi I got multiple recv() of random sizes, seemed to be around couple hundred Kb.  Think that proves it happens at least.  Interestingly if you enable SSL the max read size goes right down to 16384 bytes meaning if you wanted to send on SSL you would HAVE to implement multiple reads or be capped to 16k messages lol

Answer (score 4):

> persuade him that we need a length and payload in the message protocol so you know where messages start/end

You definitely need to, and if you need to persuade your coworker to do so, have *them* explain why not. One send() does not correspond to one recv(), period. That it might happen under certain conditions, sure. Internet is fast these days, and Nagle is enabled by default.

Try the opposite, send 1000 small messages and have them dissect the separate messages from the result of one or more recv() calls; they can't without proper message framing.

Comment: I did break their side by sending two payload in one send, and two halfs in two sends, they refuse to accept that if I hadn't maliciously done that then it would have worked (ie TCP would have ensured that their 1 recv() would get one message).

Comment: Plus I feel like actually showing them the split happens will prove beyond a shadow of a doubt, as far as they are concerned if it doesn't happen it doesn't exist

Comment: Also, we did eventually get the length in the protocol, I use it my side, but he doesnt, he just issues a recv() and say he will get one message if i send one message, he doesnt read the length, then read the payload of that length

Comment: Does your protocol offer the ability to slap the receiving side in the face?

Comment: Point is; tcp guarantees in-order delivery of data, not messages. Berkeley sockets are documented as a call to `recv()` returning **what is in the receive buffer**. Good for your coworker that up till now entire messages were in that buffer, but this is not in any way guaranteed. One network hiccup, one lost and retransmitted packet, one OS deciding to return half of a message sitting in the buffer _now_, and their code will break. When they interpret the docs in the way they assume it works, yes, the docs mention messages - but that's UDP, not TCP. TCP doesn't speak messages, it streams.

Comment: So to answer your question: you can simulate this by throttling your NIC, causing the OS to send small packets with a long time in between.

Comment: Is throttling the NIC easy?  Do i need special software?

Answer (score 4):

Your colleague is dangerously wrong. You simply cannot get a guarantee from being unable to think of, or observe, a way something can go wrong. Either there is a guarantee that receives will correspond to sends or there is not.

Observations are not helpful here.

1. If you don't observe receives not corresponding to sends, it could be a bug in the implementation in which you observe it.
2. If you do observe receives corresponding to sends, it could be because of something unusual about the implementations you are testing on and the very next version of he OS, compiler, standard library, or the like might not follow the assumptions.

Either your colleague is relying on guaranteed behavior or they are not. And the answer is that they are not.

True story from the late 90's: I once had to debug some code that "always worked just fine" because it expected the first 12 bytes of a TCP connection to stay stuck together. It broke when an attack was discovered that involved using 8 specially crafted malicious bytes and the defense used at a customer's location was a filter that intercepted and checked the first eight bytes of all TCP connections before passing them on to the application. As a result, the application always read the first 8 bytes (from the filter) on its first call to `recv`, violating the (broken, idiotic) assumption that a read for 12 bytes at the beginning of a TCP connection would always get all 12.

Comment: So basically, it could all work fine in the factory, then we deploy to a customer site, and their specific infrastructure could manifest the problem.  Thanks I will use this as another tact